# Filter and sort a list with regex in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to filter a list to get matching item from a pattern with regex, I want to get next match if first pattern doesn't exist.

What I have now

```
all_list= ["FOO tic FOO", "BAR toc", "FOO BAR" ]
pattern = ".*tic.*"
filter_list = filter(lambda x: re.findall(pattern,x),all_list)
print filter_list
```

this gives me

```
["FOO tic FOO"]
```

What I want is if **FOO tic FOO** doesn't exists in the list I want to search for next pattern, I have tried this

```
all_list= ["FOO FOO FOO", "BAR toc", "FOO BAR" ]
pattern = ".*tic.*|.*toc"
filter_list = filter(lambda x: re.findall(pattern,x),all_list)
print filter_list
```

result is as expected

```
['BAR toc']
```

but the problem is when there are both pattern matching items in the list I get both in the result where I want one which matches with  first pattern.

```
all_list= ["BAR toc","FOO tic FOO", "FOO BAR" ]
pattern = ".*tic.*|.*toc"
filter_list = filter(lambda x: re.findall(pattern,x),all_list)
print filter_list
```

result is

```
['BAR toc', 'FOO tic FOO']
```

I am expecting
`['FOO tic FOO']` or list of all matches in same order as in pattern - `['FOO tic FOO','BAR toc']` so I can get item by its index like *filter_list[0]*

Comment: `|` means "OR" in regex. If you want something like "if ... then ... else", then you have to do it outside the regex using 2 separate regexes.

Comment: Thanks for immediate response, Yes that will be my last option, I was wondering if there are any simpler method to achieve this.

Comment: I think you can list multiple patterns and filter the list starting the first pattern. If the filtered list is empty, use the second pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could list the patterns and loop them. After filtering, check if there is a result.

If there is not, go to the next pattern, else get the result.

```
import re

patterns = [
    r".*\btic\b",
    r".*\btoc\b"
]

all_list= ["BAR toc","FOO tic FOO", "FOO BAR"]
for pattern in patterns:
    filter_list = list(filter(lambda x: re.search(pattern, x), all_list))
    if len(filter_list) > 0:
        print(filter_list)
        break
```

Output

```
['FOO tic FOO']
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/wA76w6)